# Computing the mean difference between elements in a list with index $i$ and the closest elements with index $(i+1)$

Tags: algorithm

I have a list that looks like this:

```
preprocessedList = {{1,5.3},{1,5.566},{1,1.4322},{2,3.443543},{2,3.444},{3,0.1223},{4,1.3243},{4,1.554343}}
```

Each element in the list is of the form $(i,j_k)$, where $i = 1,2,3,...,N$ is an integer index (which may be degenerate, i.e. there may be multiple list entries with the same $i$ value), and $j_k$ is some value associated with each list item.

I want to create a new list $L$ where, for each index starting with $i = 2$, we compute the median or mean of the difference between elements with the index $(i-1)$ and the nearest elements with index $i$ (in terms of one-dimensional Euclidean distance).

Using the about example list:

Starting with $i = 2$, we first take {1,5.3}, we compute that {2,3.444} is closest since the different between 3.444 and 5.3 is the minimum for all items with the index $i=2$.  We compute this difference as $(3.444 - 5.3) = -1.856$.  We then move on to {1,5.566}, notice again that {2,3.444} is closest to {1,5.3}, and compute this difference as $(3.444 - 5.566) = -2.122$.  Finally, we move on to {1,1.4322}, notice that this is closest to {2,3.443543}, and compute the difference $(3.443543 - 1.4322) = 2.011343$.  We then average these differences: $(-1.856 + -2.122 + 2.011343) / 3 = -0.6555...$ and place this at position $(i-1)$ in $L$.

So we have $L = (-0.6555..., ...)$ thus far.  We then move on to $i = 3$ and so forth.  Note that if there is no $i = 3$ elements, we'd just enter $0$ at that position in $L$.

Is there a fast and slick way to do this with a large initial preprocessedList?

Here's the naive (very slow) way to do this:

```
preprocessedList = {{1, 5.3}, {1, 5.566}, {1, 1.4322}, {2, 3.443543}, {2, 3.444}, {3, 0.1223}, {4, 1.3243}, {4, 1.554343}};

L = Array[0 &, Max[preprocessedList[[All, 1]]] - (Min[preprocessedList[[All, 1]]])];

counter = 0;
For[i = Min[preprocessedList[[All, 1]]] + 1, 
  i <= Max[preprocessedList[[All, 1]]], i++,

  counter += 1;

  highIndexList = Select[preprocessedList, #[[1]] == i &];
  lowIndexList = Select[preprocessedList, #[[1]] == (i - 1) &];

  If[Length[highIndexList] > 0 && Length[lowIndexList] > 0,

      differenceArray = Array[0 &, Length[lowIndexList]];
      For[k = 1, k <= Length[lowIndexList], k++,
       differenceArray[[k]] = 
         Nearest[highIndexList[[All, 2]], lowIndexList[[k, 2]]] - lowIndexList[[k, 2]];
      ];
  L[[counter]] = {i, Mean[Flatten[differenceArray]]};
  ,
  L[[counter]] = 0;
  ];

 ];
```

The output is:

```
L = {{2, -0.655552}, {3, -3.32147}, {4, 1.202}};
```

Perhaps there's a way to compile this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't say that `preprocessedList` will always be sorted, so I sorted it.
Also, I'm not sure if this is how you want to handle gaps in the index sequence.

```
f[{{i_,x_},{j_,y_}}] := {j, If[j==i+1, Mean[Nearest[y,#][[1]]-#&/@x], 0};

f /@ Partition[{#[[1,1]],#[[All,2]]}&/@SplitBy[Sort@preprocessedList,First],2,1]

(* {{2, -0.655552}, {3, -3.32147}, {4, 1.202}} *)
```

EDIT - Here is new code that implements suggestions by Jonie and Mr.Wizard. It inserts a sequence of `(index,0}` terms instead of just one, and uses a `NearestFunction` instead of repeating `Nearest[y,#]`. Also, it assumes (as they seem to have done) that the preprocessing has sorted the data with respect to the indices.

```
f2[{{i_,x_},{j_,y_}}] := If[j==i+1, {j, Mean[Flatten[Nearest@y/@x]-x]},
                                     Sequence@@Table[{k,0},{k,i+1,j}]]

g[data_] := f2 /@ Partition[{#[[1,1]],#[[All,2]]}&/@SplitBy[data,First],2,1]

data = {{1,5.3},{1,5.566},{1,1.4322},{2,3.443543},{2,3.444},
        {3,0.1223},{4,1.3243},{4,1.554343},{7,17},{7,13},{8,4},{8,6}};

g@data

(* {{2, -0.655552}, {3, -3.32147}, {4, 1.202}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8, -9}} *)
```

Comment: he mentioned if there's no element for an i, it just returns 0. +1 for slick and efficient implementation!

Comment: I worked on this independently, and I came up with a similar method (though I believe using `NearestFunction` is superior).  I must say my code looks rather long by comparison. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I considered using a `NearestFunction` but it was so clean and short this way that I couldn't resist.

Comment: It takes next to no additional code length; please see my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know more about your data.  For example, on average how many times will a single index appear?  That can dramatically affect the best way to approach this problem I believe.

Anyway, making the assumption that these index groups may be quite large I suggest building `NearestFunction` objects.  Something like this:

```
fn[pp_] :=
  Module[{group, del},
    group[#[[1, 1]]] = #[[All, 2]]; & ~Scan~ GatherBy[pp, First];
    group[_] := 0;
    del = With[{a = group[# - 1], b = group[#]},
      If[a === 0 || b === 0, 0, Mean[First /@ Nearest[b] /@ a - a]]] &;
    Table[{i, del[i]}, {i, 1 + Min@#, Max@#}] & @ pp[[All, 1]]
  ]
```

Test:

```
{{1, 5.3}, {1, 5.566}, {1, 1.4322}, {2, 3.443543}, {2, 3.444}, {3, 0.1223},
 {4, 1.3243}, {4, 1.554343}, {7, 17}, {7, 13}, {8, 4}, {8, 6}} // fn
```

> ```
> {{2, -0.655552}, {3, -3.32147}, {4, 1.202}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8, -9}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the functional naive but slightly faster implementation:

```
f3[lis_] := Module[{},  
     min = Min[lis[[All, 1]]];
     max = Max[lis[[All, 1]]];
     t = Table[Select[lis, #[[1]] == i &], {i, min, max}];
     Table[
        If[Length[t[[i]]] == 0 || Length[t[[i - 1]]] == 0,
           {i, 0},  
           nearestValues = 
              Flatten[Nearest[t[[i, All, 2]], #] & /@ t[[i - 1, All, 2]]];
           {i, Mean[MapThread[(#1 - #2) &, {nearestValues, Flatten[t[[i - 1, All, 2]]]}]]}]
         , {i, min + 1, max}
     ]
]
```

Using

```
data = MapThread[List, {Sort[Table[RandomInteger[{1, 50}], {i, 10000}]],
       Table[RandomReal[{-5, 5}], {j, 10000}]}];

f3[data] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.697170

And the original implementation

```
f1[lis_] := Module[{},
    L = Array[0 &, Max[lis[[All, 1]]] - (Min[lis[[All, 1]]])];
    counter = 0;
    For[i = Min[lis[[All, 1]]] + 1, i <= Max[lis[[All, 1]]], i++, 
        counter += 1;
        highIndexList = Select[lis, #[[1]] == i &];
        lowIndexList = Select[lis, #[[1]] == (i - 1) &];
        If[Length[highIndexList] > 0 && Length[lowIndexList] > 0, 
            differenceArray = Array[0 &, Length[lowIndexList]];
            For[k = 1, k <= Length[lowIndexList], k++, 
            differenceArray[[k]] = 
            Nearest[highIndexList[[All, 2]], lowIndexList[[k, 2]]] - lowIndexList[[k, 2]];];
            L[[counter]] = {i, Mean[Flatten[differenceArray]]};, 
            L[[counter]] = 0;
        ];
    ];
    L
]

f1[data] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 2.263226

Using ParalleTable for f3 yields 0.894089 (presuming kernels already started)

Ray Koopman's method yields 1.093109 for the same data. With Parallelize wrapper, 0.343034.

```
f[{{i_, x_}, {j_, y_}}] := {j, 
    If[j == i + 1, Mean[Nearest[y, #][[1]] - # & /@ x], 0]};

Parallelize[
   f /@ Partition[{#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@ 
   SplitBy[Sort@data, First], 2, 1]] //  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.343034